# How to make schema diagram in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

In schema diagram one attribute(foreign key) points another attribute of different table. I can point table to table, but not attribute to attribute.

You just modify my following MWE that give the following result. One arrow from `dept_name` of `instructor` to `dept_name` of `department`.

[image]

MWE(taken from @marmot)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{basic/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        text width=2cm,
        align=left,
        font=\itshape
    },
    Diamond/.style={ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 2pt,
                        text centered,
                        fill=blue!10!white,
                        font=\itshape
                      }}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[basic] (instructor) {instructor
\nodepart{second}
\underline{ID}\\
name\\
salary};
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor] (department) {department
\nodepart{second}
\underline{dept\_name}\\
building\\
budget};
\draw (instructor) -- (department);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output of my MWE

[image]

Comment: I want to something like `\draw (instructor.dept\_name) -> (department.budget)`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{basic/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        minimum width=2.5cm,
        text width=2cm,
        align=left,
        font=\itshape
    },
    Diamond/.style={ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 2pt,
                        text centered,
                        fill=blue!10!white,
                        font=\itshape
                      }}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[basic] (instructor) {instructor
\nodepart{second}
\underline{ID}\\
name\\
dept\_name\\
salary};
\node[basic,right=5cm of instructor] (department) {department
\nodepart{second}
\underline{dept\_name}\\
building\\
budget};
\draw[->] ([yshift=-13pt]$(instructor.east)$) -- ([yshift=1pt]$(department.west)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]